# View elements resize problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UiView` which contains a `UiWebview`, `UIButton` and a `UITextView` as its elements.
I add this UiView to a UIScrollView and resize the frame so that the text view is not visible. When i click the button i resize the view to display the entire UIView including the UItextview.

The problem is , the text view appears below the view when i resize the frame. When i click expand it covers the text view too.

When view is first added i want the view to display just the webview and the button and when button is pressed it should display the text view.

[image: When view is added with resized frame] [image: When button is clicked i resize the frame to show text view too]

How do i achieve it? Has it got to do with view hierachy?

Comment: Can you show us some code? What are you doing to resize the frame back?

Comment: Its simple resize where i set the frame size. Will add some code if clipping as suggested by @thomas doesnt work.

Comment: Has it got to do with the layout of the subviews. With enabling clipping the uitextview now overlaps the webview and when expanded is shown below the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should enable [clipping](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds) on the `UIView` .

**edit:**
I wouldn't resize the view. Instead I would just change the [`hidden`-property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden) on the textview. If you want to add some animations later then you can modify the `alpha`-property as well.

Comment: I enabled clipping and it solves the problem half way though. The text view now gets placed on the visible portion of the uiview. I want the position of text view not to change. +1 for clipping.